# Masking / changing url with htaccess - wordpress slug

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, slug

For a new Wordpress website of mine I'm running into a little problem.

There is a custom post type named 'vehicle' which uses the url slug 'vehicle'.

The thing is, my website isn't aimed at cars, but at boats, so I want to change the url to www.domain.com/boats/boatname1 instead of www.domain.com/vehicle/boatname1.

I have succeeded in editing the slug using the following code - after which I flushed the rewrite url's and changed permalinks back and forth:

`function change_vehicle_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $rewrite = &$wp_post_types['vehicle']->rewrite;
    $rewrite['slug'] = 'horses';
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_vehicle_rewrite_rules', 999 );`

On my homepage, there are nog links showing www.domain.com/boats/boatname, but when I click on them, I get a 404. If I change the url to www.domain.com/vehicle/boatname it DOES work. So the url's have changed, but the working post is still shown under /vehicle/  instead of under /boats/.

Is there a way, perhaps using .htaccess, so that EVERY url on my website that shows /vehicle/  is changed to /boats/ ?

Or perhaps a way that when I click on a link www.domain.com/boats/boatname that it SHOWS the /vehicle/ content, but shows /boats/ in the URL.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Mike

Comment: I don't think that tampering with .htaccess will do any good. While you might work around this issue (for example passing a ```type=vehicle``` when the url has 'boat' in it, it will lead to breaking something further down the line. Worpress needs to handle everything through its internal rewrite logic. You should try to keep the vehicle type but change its slug to boats before trying any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

How many different URL's are we talking here? If it's not a huge amount, you can look into one of the text replace plugins and specify each original URL, and what you want the text to be replaced with (ie: from "vehicle" to "boats")

http://wordpress.org/plugins/text-replace/